# "Transitions" with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just wanted to know whether there was a way to do something like a CSS transition with JavaScript.

Here is a fiddle with my current simple game: http://jsfiddle.net/pLu84wuk/

Basically, on line 249:

```
document.getElementById('lossScreen').style.display = 'block';
```

This code is what makes the loss screen pop up. However, I would like it to fade in, or at least have some better transition so that it looks smoother when it comes into view. Is there a way to do this with JavaScript? This is the styling for the loss screen if it is any help:

```
#lossScreen {
  display: none;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #001400;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2px;;
}

#lossScreen h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#lossScreen p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#lossScreen #finalScore {
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , another way of fade in effect. Using opacity as for the transition , take note remove the style `display:none`

```
#lossScreen {
  display: none; //remove this
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #001400;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; //add this for transition
 -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; //add this for transition
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; //add this for transition
  opacity:0; //add this for transition
}
```

and edit this line to

```
document.getElementById('lossScreen').style.opacity= '1';
```

Comment: This almost works, the problem is that because there is no `display: none', the button choices are being blocked by the invisible loss screen. I managed to make it work by messing around with z-indexes, but is there a cleaner way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you just use JQuery instead of Javascript. It's so much simpler. All you need to do is link to JQuery and type the fadeIn effect.

```js
    $("#lossScreen ").fadeIn();
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pure JavaScript > jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I did pretty much the entire thing without jQuery and I'd rather just figure it out this last part with just vanilla JS rather than using jQuery for one small thing.